# JQuery - Deserializing an XML object into a class type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a javascript test project where i am trying to deserialize an XML document (loaded from a remote XML file) into a locally defined class object.

I am unsure how to go about achieving this.
How to deserialize an XML object into a javascript class type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

$title.text() would return your title value

Comment: This is something that i already do. the $.parseXML is simply converting the string to an XML document. What i need is the ability to convert this XML (whether string or xdoc) into a javascript class type object.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar yes, but if you have a xml document you can recursively iterate through it and create objects for each value

Comment: Yes, i failed to mention that is currently what i am doing. But im finding that my code to do the conversion is getting into specific cases that im having to handle. So i would looking for a more flexible/uniform way of doing the conversion, hence the deserialization.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar maybe this link will help you: http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar this one tested by me seems also to work: http://jsfiddle.net/3ngSn/